# How to prevent XCode debugger from stopping on object code?

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I am debugging my application using breakpoints. Often when the debugger is stopped at a breakpoint and  I hit "Continue program execution", the debugger does not go to my next breakpoint but instead stops at some object code, for example `objc_msgsend` and then it just gets stuck there - I hit continue, but never get to my actual next breakpoint, it always gets into the `objc_msgsend` and the only way to get out of the situation is to stop the app completely.

How do I tell XCode debugger not to stop where it is not asked to?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your exception breakpoint and select objective C.